# Grails lagan Integration

Tags: web-services, grails, soap

I have a grails project where I need to place a report in a CRM called Lagan. I am using grails cxf client for accessing SOAP web services of Lagan. By following the example given in  https://github.com/Grails-Plugin-Consortium/grails-cxf-client-demo
I am not able to correctly set the configuration parameters in conf file. I got a user name and password and url for accessing the lagan server which is part of a website.
Does anybody have experience in integraing with Lagan?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with new web service is always hard part. I found useful to first figure out correct SOAP envelope. For example using this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wizdler/oebpmncolmhiapingjaagmapififiakb plugin. When you have envelope that is working fine you can start troubleshooting your library. Review SOAP differences.